How can I use a Provider to store changes to a TextEditingController's text without causing the widget to reload its text?
I am making a note taking app and managing the app's state using Provider. When a user selects aNote object (from a List<Note> stored in the Provider), the selected Note's title and content fields are displayed in two TextField widgets. One widget stores selectedNote.title, the other selectedNote.content. Each TextField has a TextEditingController
When a user changes the value of a TextField, I want to call an update method in my Provider.
The problem I have is that calling update triggers widget rebuilding. When the TextField widgets are rebuilt, the TextEditingController reassigns their text, and the cursor moves to the end of the TextFields.
I tried using context.read<Data>().update(), thinking context.read<T>() would avoid widget rebuilds--but that didn't happen.
I also tried putting the TextFields in separate widgets, thinking their parent might rebuild without the children rebuilding--but that didn't happen.
For reference, here are snippets of the key code (Note is a simple data model class with String title, String content fields):
From the Provider
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Note> notes = [];
  Note selectedNote = Note('', ''); 
  
  void update({title = '', content = ''}) {
    // Don't do anything if user hasn't selected a note
    if (selectedNote.title != '' || selectedNote.content != '') {
      if (title != '') selectedNote.title = title;
      if (content != '') selectedNote.content = content;
      notifyListeners();
      writeJson(); //<--separate method; not important to my question
    }
  }

From the display widget
class _NoteDetailState extends State<NoteDetail> {
  final TextEditingController noteTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController noteContentController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    noteContentController.dispose();
    noteTitleController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Note? selectedNote = context.read<Data>().selectedNote;
    
        return DefaultTabController(
      // ...code...
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  // Note's Title TextField---------------------------------
                  NoteTextField(
                    displayText: selectedNote.title,
                    controller: noteTitleController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      context.read<Data>().update(title: value);
                    },
                    minLines: 1,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!,
                  ),
                  // Note's Content TextField---------------------------------
                  NoteTextField(
                    displayText: selectedNote.content,
                    controller: noteContentController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      context.read<Data>().update(content: value);
                    },
                    minLines: 10,
                  ),
        // ...more code...

The Widget for the NoteTextField:
class NoteTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoteTextField(
      {super.key,
      required this.displayText,
      required this.controller,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.minLines,
      this.style});

  final String displayText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Function(String) onChanged;
  final int minLines;
  final TextStyle? style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.text = displayText;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 15,
        bottom: 15,
      ),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        style: style,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
        onChanged: onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}

p.s. I do need to call notifyListeners() to update values elsewhere in the app. I want widgets to rebuild elsewhere in the app, just not in the fields that cause the TextField cursor to jump.

This won't stop the rebuilding but instead it will move the cursor to the end of the line.
 controller;
      ..text = displayText
      ..selection = TextSelection(
        baseOffset: displayText.length,
        extentOffset: displayText.length,
      );


Thanks for replying. I don't actually want the cursor to move to the end of the line; I don't want it to move anywhere. It moves to the end of the line now, and that makes editing text impossible. I did, though, try a similar strategy--find the cursor position, call Provider.update(), put the cursor in the same position (TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: originalCursorPosition))) ... Didn't work.

My fault. I didn't understand your question correctly at first but I do now. context.read should prevent rebuilding as it doesn't listen to changes. Since you are saying it didn't work. Are you using context.watch in the parent/s of NoteDetailWidget? Maybe the parent rebuilds which rebuilds children as well.

Also you can use onEditingComplete instead of onChanged or have a separate button to call the update function that users can click to submit the changes.

The only context.watch in the app is in main(), when all the widgets are built, so you could be onto something! Everything rebuilds when the app is resized, too. … Do you think there’s a way to skip rebuilding the TextField or TextEfitingController at these times?

since you use context.watch in your main() the whole app would rebuilt in case of any state changes. There is not much you can do to prevent to the child from rebuilding when the parent rebuilds. The only workaround as I mentioned before is to use onEditingComplete instead of onChanged which cause a rebuild when the user presses the done button.  Or what you can do instead is to have a separate button which will call the update function and totally get rid of onChanged and onEditingComplete. These changes will limit the number of rebuilds.
